# Manually enter shipping costs when placing an order via webservice

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

Currently I am working on export orders from ebay to prestashop through my local application. 
I fetching orders from eBay by API and I prepare the order as XML and send by Presta webservice to my webshop. I do not know how to solve the problem with shipping costs. On eBay I have a different shipping than in my shop, so I do not want to choose a carrier when ordering, but give a "shipping cost" manually. There is a possibility?

Comment: Is this Prestashop 1.5 or 1.6 ?

Comment: Shipping in Prestashop is dynamic - it depends on customer address, products. There is no place to change a shipping cost manually unless you'll get a custom module for that. But you can use a trick: make "Free shipping" for these orders, then edit an order in your Prestashop backoffice and add a product called "Shipping" with any value you want, and hide "Free shipping" in orders invoices, emails etc. Though some coding is needed.

Comment: That seems to make sense. My accounting software automatically hides free shipping.